# Outlook to Gmail Spacing Issues

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, gmail

I'm trying to put together some email signatures but am running in to issues when sending from outlook to gmail. Sending the signature from gmail to outlook looks good - and the signature looks good in the outlook client. BUT as soon as the email is sent from outlook to gmail it adds spacing and messes things up a little. I've done some research and tried to implement fixes but no luck as of yet.

[Here is the email displaying correctly in outlook:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/541EE.png) and [here it is displaying incorrectly once recieved by gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDcsK.png)

Weird thing is it works fine when sending from gmail, so something must be happening when along the way from outlook > gmail. Any tips would be greatly appreciated! I know my code isn't great, just a graphic designer battling my way through email styling!

**UPDATE: It seems that this code in gmail is the issue, is there any way of overwriting this?[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Ive.png)**

Code below:

```
<head>
    <style>
    span, p, td, tr {color:#24406d; line-height: 90%;mso-line-height: taro-papo; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
    </style>
</head>
<html>
<body>
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 320px; background: white;">
    <tr><td><hr></td></tr>
<td><span style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: 600;">Name Nameson</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px;">Customer Service Manager</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><hr></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span style="font-weight: 600;">P.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>07 1111 1111</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span style="font-weight: 600;">M.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>0401 111 111</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td><span style="font-weight: 600;">E.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>test@venetablinds.com.au</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span style="font-weight: 600;">A.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>13/14 Argyle St, Albion QLD 4010</td></tr>
    <tr><td><span style="font-weight: 600;">W.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>www.venetablinds.com.au</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1xze-aa3lvrf6Rrvl0Krb5G2sfVA2LZFm" width="320px"></tr>
<tr><td><span style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <a><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1jiViwT0NnYrNSeUbfjh1RwbyMfL4IACa"></a> 
    <a><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1S1wRD6Fqx8MqDu0RlCYauhgWiBMVCLyo"></a> 
    <a><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=18yiUbFJ4NAapVLkMBBrAvo-HrQFNZ6-e"></a></td></span></tr>
</span>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You have to give `cellpadding="0"` and `cellspacing="0"` in `table` and we have change your HTML structure for desired output.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/rhL0p7nw/3/

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    span,
    p,
    td,
    tr {
      color: #24406d;
      line-height: 90%;
      mso-line-height: taro-papo;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="width: 320px; background: white;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <hr>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: 600;">Name Nameson</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px;">Customer Service Manager</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <hr>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="font-weight: 600;">P.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>07 1111 1111</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="font-weight: 600;">M.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>0401 111 111</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="font-weight: 600;">E.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>test@venetablinds.com.au</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="font-weight: 600;">A.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>13/14 Argyle St, Albion QLD 4010</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="font-weight: 600;">W.</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>www.venetablinds.com.au</span></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1xze-aa3lvrf6Rrvl0Krb5G2sfVA2LZFm" width="320px">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1jiViwT0NnYrNSeUbfjh1RwbyMfL4IACa"></a>
        <a><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1S1wRD6Fqx8MqDu0RlCYauhgWiBMVCLyo"></a>
        <a><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=18yiUbFJ4NAapVLkMBBrAvo-HrQFNZ6-e"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Please check resulted image:

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking the time to look in to this, really appreciate it. Unfortunately the problem is still occuring, I've added an amendment to my inital post of the code that is overriding my line height styling. Not sure if there is any way to override that!

Comment: For the line-height issue, you can add it along with font-size. It may solve your issue.